# Перемещение ВСЕХ ТОЧЕК в pyqtgraph

Tags: python, gui, pyqtgraph, plotwidget

[https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1317315/Перемещение-точек-графика-pyqtgraph](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1317315/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BA-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-pyqtgraph)
Я прикреплю старую тему. Да, очень помог S. Nick.

Но !
Проблема заключается в определении точек. Они всегда возвращают одну и ту же.

[image: Точка посередине]

Допустим я хочу переместить ту точку, которая посередине. 
Ок. 
Перемещаю, вывожу какая она (должна быть **`1`**).

[image: Точка перемещённая]

Да. Это действительно первая (вторая сверху точка) 
Верно. 
График приведу.

[image: Перемещённая точка в середине]

Но! Когда я пытаюсь переместить самую первую точку в координате (1, 1) , она выводит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему значение точки по прежнему **`1`**, хотя должно быть **`0`**? Как быть?
Ведь метод isFinish() должен обнулить её. Почему этого не происходит?

```
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui

pg.setConfigOptions(antialias=True)

w = pg.PlotWidget()
w.setWindowTitle('Draggable')


class Graph(pg.GraphItem):
    def __init__(self):
        self.dragPoint = None
        self.dragOffset = None
        pg.GraphItem.__init__(self)

    def setData(self, **kwds):
        self.data = kwds
        if 'pos' in self.data:
            npts = self.data['pos'].shape[0]
            self.data['adj'] = np.column_stack(
                (np.arange(0, npts-1), np.arange(1, npts))
            )
            self.data['data'] = np.empty(npts, dtype=[('index', int)])
            self.data['data']['index'] = np.arange(npts)
        self.updateGraph()

    def updateGraph(self):
        pg.GraphItem.setData(self, **self.data)

    def mouseDragEvent(self, ev):
        if ev.button() != QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            ev.ignore()
            return
        if ev.isStart():
            pos = ev.buttonDownPos()
            pts = self.scatter.pointsAt(pos)
            if len(pts) == 0:
                ev.ignore()
                return
                
            self.dragPoint = pts[0]
            ind = pts[0].data()[0]
            self.dragOffset = self.data['pos'][ind][1] - pos[1]
        elif ev.isFinish():
            self.dragPoint = None
            return
        else:
            if self.dragPoint is None:
                ev.ignore()
                return

        ind = self.dragPoint.data()[0]
        self.data['pos'][ind][1] = ev.pos()[1] + self.dragOffset
        self.data['pos'][ind][0] = ev.pos()[0] + self.dragOffset
        self.updateGraph()
        print(ev.pos(),self.dragPoint.data()[0])
        ev.accept()


g = Graph()
v = w.addPlot()
v.addItem(g)

#                      v <---- попробуйте изменить значение
x = np.linspace(1, 10, 3)

pos = np.column_stack((x, np.sin(x)))
g.setData(pos=pos, size=10, pxMode=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: Извините, уже разобрался

Comment: Просто у меня есть класс Graphic. Он унаследован от PlotWidget. И я не понимаю как соединить GraphicsWindow и PlotWidget

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui


app = pg.mkQApp()                                               # +++
 
pg.setConfigOptions(antialias=True)


class Graph(pg.GraphItem):
    def __init__(self):
        self.dragPoint = None
        self.dragOffset = None
        pg.GraphItem.__init__(self)   

    def setData(self, **kwds):
        self.data = kwds
        if 'pos' in self.data:
            npts = self.data['pos'].shape[0]
            self.data['adj'] = np.column_stack(
                (np.arange(0, npts-1), np.arange(1, npts))
            )
            self.data['data'] = np.empty(npts, dtype=[('index', int)])
            self.data['data']['index'] = np.arange(npts)
        self.updateGraph()

    def updateGraph(self):
        pg.GraphItem.setData(self, **self.data)

    def mouseDragEvent(self, ev):
        if ev.button() != QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            ev.ignore()
            return
        if ev.isStart():
            pos = ev.buttonDownPos()
            pts = self.scatter.pointsAt(pos)
            if len(pts) == 0:
                ev.ignore()
                return
                
            self.dragPoint = pts[0]
            ind = pts[0].data()[0]
            self.dragOffset = self.data['pos'][ind][1] - pos[1]
        elif ev.isFinish():
            self.dragPoint = None
            return
        else:
            if self.dragPoint is None:
                ev.ignore()
                return

        ind = self.dragPoint.data()[0]
        self.data['pos'][ind][1] = ev.pos()[1] + self.dragOffset
        self.data['pos'][ind][0] = ev.pos()[0] + self.dragOffset
        self.updateGraph()
        print(ev.pos(),self.dragPoint.data()[0])
        ev.accept()

g = Graph()

pw = pg.PlotWidget(title="PlotItem")                            # +++
pw.addItem(g)                                                   # +++
pw.show()                                                       # +++

#                      v <---- попробуйте изменить значение
x = np.linspace(1, 10, 3)

pos = np.column_stack((x, np.sin(x)))
g.setData(pos=pos, size=10, pxMode=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Работает, спасибо)

Comment: Извините, а вы не могли бы подсказать как установить метки у данных точек? Ну к примеру при наведении на точку показывался бы её размер? Как это выполнить?

Comment: @РоманАртамонов задайте новый вопрос, приложите свой код и лучше опишите что вы хотите сделать.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1345916/Метки-на-графике-pyqtgraph