# Метки ToolTip на графике PyQtGraph

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqtgraph, tooltip

У меня есть график, как этот:

```
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui

pg.setConfigOptions(antialias=True)

w = pg.PlotWidget()
w.setWindowTitle('Draggable')


class Graph(pg.GraphItem):
    def __init__(self):
        self.dragPoint = None
        self.dragOffset = None
        pg.GraphItem.__init__(self)

    def setData(self, **kwds):
        self.data = kwds
        if 'pos' in self.data:
            npts = self.data['pos'].shape[0]
            self.data['adj'] = np.column_stack(
                (np.arange(0, npts-1), np.arange(1, npts))
            )
            self.data['data'] = np.empty(npts, dtype=[('index', int)])
            self.data['data']['index'] = np.arange(npts)
        self.updateGraph()

    def updateGraph(self):
        pg.GraphItem.setData(self, **self.data)

    def mouseDragEvent(self, ev):
        if ev.button() != QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            ev.ignore()
            return
        if ev.isStart():
            pos = ev.buttonDownPos()
            pts = self.scatter.pointsAt(pos)
            if len(pts) == 0:
                ev.ignore()
                return
                
            self.dragPoint = pts[0]
            ind = pts[0].data()[0]
            self.dragOffset = self.data['pos'][ind][1] - pos[1]
        elif ev.isFinish():
            self.dragPoint = None
            return
        else:
            if self.dragPoint is None:
                ev.ignore()
                return

        ind = self.dragPoint.data()[0]
        self.data['pos'][ind][1] = ev.pos()[1] + self.dragOffset
        self.data['pos'][ind][0] = ev.pos()[0] + self.dragOffset
        self.updateGraph()
        print(ev.pos(),self.dragPoint.data()[0])
        ev.accept()


g = Graph()
v = w.addPlot()
v.addItem(g)

#                      v <---- попробуйте изменить значение
x = np.linspace(1, 10, 3)

pos = np.column_stack((x, np.sin(x)))
g.setData(pos=pos, size=10, pxMode=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

Пользователь @S.Nick, очень помог.
Теперь я хочу создать метки на нём.
Я создал подписи точек при помощи:

```
for i,j,k in zip(*self.table.UNIQUIE_X):
            k[str(list(k.keys())[0])].setPos(i, j)
            k[str(list(k.keys())[0])].setToolTip('x='+str(i)+','+'y='+str(j))
            self.view.addItem(k[str(list(k.keys())[0])])
```

И этот код отлично работает! Я заметил, что класс поддерживает свойство **`setToolTip`** (добавление метки). В коде, в цикле `for` я задаю просто подписи. И ставлю метки на них (всплывающие подсказки). 
Но! Когда я навожу курсор мыши на точку, то метка убирается.

Как быть? Мне нужны метки не на подписях, а при наведении на точку!

Скрин прикрепляю, это то, что есть на данный момент:

[image: картинка]

Итак внесу правки. Я разобрался более-менее в чём проблема. В данной реализации там указывается `symbol`. Но как я могу применить и изменить его на `ScatterPlotItem`? Т.е. мне в структуре нужно указать точки, только не как `symbol`, а как `ScatterPlotItem`. 
Как это выполнить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант, попробуйте.

```
import sys
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui


app = pg.mkQApp()                  
pg.setConfigOptions(antialias=True)


class Graph(pg.GraphItem):
    def __init__(self, pw):
        self.pw = pw
        self.dragPoint = None
        self.dragOffset = None
        pg.GraphItem.__init__(self)   

    def setData(self, **kwds):
        self.data = kwds
        if 'pos' in self.data:
            npts = self.data['pos'].shape[0]
            self.data['adj'] = np.column_stack(
                (np.arange(0, npts-1), np.arange(1, npts))
            )
            self.data['data'] = np.empty(npts, dtype=[('index', int)])
            self.data['data']['index'] = np.arange(npts)
        self.updateGraph()

    def updateGraph(self):
        pg.GraphItem.setData(self, **self.data)

    def mouseDragEvent(self, ev):
        if ev.button() != QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            ev.ignore()
            return
        if ev.isStart():
            pos = ev.buttonDownPos()
            pts = self.scatter.pointsAt(pos)
            if len(pts) == 0:
                ev.ignore()
                return
                
            self.dragPoint = pts[0]
            ind = pts[0].data()[0]
            self.dragOffset = self.data['pos'][ind][1] - pos[1]
        elif ev.isFinish():
            self.dragPoint = None
            return
        else:
            if self.dragPoint is None:
                ev.ignore()
                return

        ind = self.dragPoint.data()[0]
        self.data['pos'][ind][1] = ev.pos()[1] + self.dragOffset
        self.data['pos'][ind][0] = ev.pos()[0] + self.dragOffset
        self.updateGraph()
        print(ev.pos(), self.dragPoint.data()[0])
        ev.accept()

# !!!    
    def hoverEvent(self, ev):        
        try:
            items = self.pw.scene().items(ev.scenePos())
        except AttributeError as e:
            return

        for item in items:
           if isinstance(item, pg.GraphItem): 
               if item.scatter.pointsAt(ev.pos()):
                   pw.setToolTip(f'<b>x={ev.pos().x():.1f}, y={ev.pos().y():.1f}</b>')
               else:
                   pw.setToolTip('')        


pw = pg.PlotWidget(title="PlotItem")
g = Graph(pw)                                                   # +++ pw

pw.addItem(g)
pw.showGrid(x=True, y=True)
pw.show()                                    

#                      v <---- попробуйте изменить значение
x = np.linspace(1, 10, 5)

pos = np.column_stack((x, np.sin(x)))
g.setData(pos=pos, size=10, pxMode=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо! Очень помогли!

Comment: @РоманАртамонов пожалуйста. Если мои  ответы учат вас чему-то новому, то не забывайте отмечать из и как полезные.

Comment: Хорошо. Я скажу сразу, просто это как часть одного крупного проекта. В целом, на данный момент у меня задача разработать приложение, позволяющее моделировать работу PID регулятора.

Comment: @РоманАртамонов хорошо что?

Comment: Я просто не пойму что значит отметить как полезные? Я так понимаю отметить просто как решения.